# Redmine doesn' start - Object is not missing constant Issue

Tags: redmine

After trying to install a new plugin (already uninstalled), my redmine application doesn't start and I really can't find what happened.

Here goes the backtrace:

```
*** Exception ArgumentError in PhusionPassenger::Railz::ApplicationSpawner (Object is not missing constant Issue!) (process 834):
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:106:in `const_missing'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:118:in `const_missing'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:124:in `send'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:124:in `const_missing'
from /usr/share/redmine/app/models/project.rb:40
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require_or_load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:451:in `load_missing_constant'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:106:in `const_missing'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:118:in `const_missing'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:463:in `load_missing_constant'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:122:in `const_missing'
from /usr/share/redmine/app/models/principal.rb:22
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require_or_load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:250:in `depend_on'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/dependencies.rb:162:in `require_dependency'
from /usr/share/redmine/vendor/plugins/redmine_git_hosting/init.rb:3:in `evaluate_init_rb'
from /usr/share/redmine/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin.rb:158:in `evaluate_init_rb'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:11:in `silence_warnings'
from /usr/share/redmine/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin.rb:154:in `evaluate_init_rb'
from /usr/share/redmine/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin.rb:48:in `load'
from /usr/share/redmine/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:38:in `load_plugins'
from /usr/share/redmine/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `each'
from /usr/share/redmine/vendor/rails/railties/lib/rails/plugin/loader.rb:37:in `load_plugins'
from /usr/share/redmine/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:369:in `load_plugins'
from /usr/share/redmine/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:165:in `process'
from /usr/share/redmine/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
from /usr/share/redmine/vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
from /usr/share/redmine/config/environment.rb:49
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:303:in `preload_application'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:252:in `initialize_server'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:255:in `report_app_init_status'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:237:in `initialize_server'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:194:in `start_synchronously'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:163:in `start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/railz/application_spawner.rb:213:in `start'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:262:in `spawn_rails_application'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:126:in `lookup_or_add'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:256:in `spawn_rails_application'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:80:in `synchronize'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:255:in `spawn_rails_application'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:154:in `spawn_application'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:287:in `handle_spawn_application'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `__send__'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:352:in `main_loop'
from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:196:in `start_synchronously'
from /usr/lib/phusion_passenger/passenger-spawn-server:61
```

Redmine version: 1.3.2.stable(MySQL)
Ruby version: 1.8.7